# How to convert a string of numbers (characters) to integer values in c

Tags: c

I need to convert an array of number characters to integer values, in order to perform math operations in C. When I use atoi(argv[2][count]), it only converts the first digit to an integer. So if argv[2]=123, it only converts the '1' to an integer 1. How can I get '123' to be one integer value, 123? Thanks!

Comment: please show the code you have tried, your problem is far from clear when you describe it.

Comment: @aroth, I don't know why I didn't think of that. That was what was wrong with it. Just a brain fart that happens from staring at the same code forever. Thanks!

Comment: If you weren't getting a compiler error message from `atoi(argv[2][count])`, then you are seriously misusing your compiler.  You need to turn on warnings for undeclared functions, and you need to include `<stdlib.h>` so that the prototype for `atoi()` is in scope, which would then tell you that you're calling the function incorrectly.  If you're using `gcc`, use `gcc -Wall` as a starting point; heed its warnings (all of them) and fix them before asking for help (unless you need help fixing a specific warning — that would be a legitimate question).

Answer (score 3):

atoi is a good function to use, however you can write your own atoi function in C.

```
int xatoi(char *s)
{
   int result=0;       

   while(*s)
   {

     result=result*10+(*s-48);
     s++; 
    }

  return result;
```

}
the logic behind this is every character '1','2',......'s ascii value is stored for example '1' has ASCII value '49'. please compile above program and check for errors i haven't tested it but i am sure it will work.

please see the link below for your reference 
http://www.newebgroup.com/rod/newillusions/ascii.htm

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is an array of string arrays and so `argv[N]` gives you an array. But `argv[N][J]` gives you element at position `J` of the array stored in `argv[N]`. However, it is strange that compiler did not complain about your code because `atoi()` function, in fact, expects a pointer (to the null-terminated string) and not a character value. The compiler should have said something like `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`. I recommend you not to ignore warnings. Personally I tend to compile the code with the highest warning level and not have a single warning, though our codebase at work is many millions of lines of code.

Also, prefer to use `strtol` over `atoi`. The problem with `atoi` is that it ignores invalid input (i.e. just returns you 0 if there is no problem, without affecting `errno`).

Anyway, here is an example of how to grab an array of base 10 integers from a command line:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  i;
    int  n;
    char    *e;
    int     *v;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please specify some numbers\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    n = argc - 1;
    v = alloca(sizeof(int) * n);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        v[i-1] = strtol(argv[i][i], &e, 10);
        if (!v && errno) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert '%s' into number: %s\n",
                argv[i], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (*e != '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a number\n", argv[i]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("You have entered the following numbers: %d", v[0]);

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        printf(", %d", v[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope it is useful.